# Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps - Dont work for me

Tags: google-maps-api-3

good morning,

I have been doing this tutorial and does not show me the markers
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=es

attached my file in case anyone can help me
http://pastebin.com/d7XhrZST          archivo.html

The php is the same is the same as the article

Thank you

Comment: **1.** "Dont work for me" doesn't tell us anything about the probelm.  Your markers aren't showing, but are you getting any errors?  **2.** Include the code you have in the question, and not a link.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive.  You have

```
var telefono = markers1[i].getAttribute("type");
```

Then you refer to it as

```
 + "<br/><b>Telefono:</b>" + Telefono
```

Notice the difference between telefono  and Telefono  - Javascript treats these as two separate variables, one of which doesn't exist.